Customize the prompt message to notify customers about their upcoming appointments in Amazon connect contact FLows in Salesforce voice
I have an use case to make automated outbound calls to customers notifying them of their upcoming appointments in the next 5 days in Salesforce omnichannel voice. I want to customize the prompt message for each customer to include the appointment scheduled date.
I have implemented  the contact Flow in Amazon Connect and added a text to speech prompt in the contact flow to play an audio message to the customer after they pick up the call. I am calling the SCV outbound call Flow APi from Salsforce and passing the appointmet date parameter . I am not sure how to add the appointmnet scheduled date to the prompt message to be played to the customer.Can any one please guide me on how this can be implemented.

Assuming that the appointmet date is attached as a user attribute (let's say $.Attributes.AppointmentDate), then in your play prompt block you can use that attribute in the prompt text e.g. Hi, this is a reminder for an upcoming appointment on $.Attributes.AppointmentDate
You may want to use SSML so that the date is spoken correctly. For example, if the AppointmentDate attribute is 2024-06-30 and you had an AppointmentTime attribute of 10:30am, then you could set the prompt text to be interpreted as SSML and enter the prompt text:
<speak>Hi, this is a reminder for an upcoming appointment on <say-as interpret-as="date" format="ymd">$.Attributes.AppointmentDate</say-as> at <say-as interpret-as="time">$.Attributes.AppointmentTime</say-as></speak>

